# executable completes, but ghci just prints a "

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am new to Haskell and have some issues with how my code evaluates.

When I write this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ "v1: " ++ show v1 ++ " v2: " ++ show v2
  where
    v1 = Goal.value (0,0) Goal.Home 39
    v2 = Goal.value (2,1) Goal.Away 50
```

and then run that program in a terminal it finishes in about 6 minutes.

But when I do a `stack ghci` or `stack exec jupyter -- notebook` the code just hangs when doing

```
Goal.value (0,0) Goal.Home 39
```

In ghci it writes a " and then nothing more.

It used to work and since I had it working I have only worked on how the parser in `TrueValue.MatchReader`.

Why am I seeing this difference? I am rather confused at this point.

I really miss having that interactive environment to work with my data.
Especially because it takes 6 minutes to do the computation, so I'd like to develop and test my functions on the `League.results` without having to wait so long for each round.

All my code is at https://github.com/lehoff/tvhs

Cheers,
Torben

Comment: This question is not sufficiently self-contained; to have any hope of debugging your code, one would need to scour the entire git repo. Consider creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try it on inputs that don't take so long? By default Ghci is interpreted, so depending on the type of code you can anticipate the potential for massive slowdowns compared to compilation.  Something that takes 6 minutes could take 60 minutes instead.

You can instead have ghci compile modules by using -fobject-code.  See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-obj.html

EDIT: I don't know why this is being downvoted.  Someone is being a negative nancy.  Sure, the guy should have more detail and repro.  But this is answerable without the omitted details.

Anyway, I forgot to mention one other thing which is that the reason `"` gets printed is due to laziness.  It can get that part of the output before the rest of it is ready.  This is probably the root of the misunderstanding here.

Comment: It's not appropriate to include commentary on voting in your answer. The answers are purely for answers to the question. Also, when you edit an answer, you should edit it so that the result doesn't look edited, since people are looking for answers, not commentary on the history of writing those answers.

Comment: This is the spot on answer. As soon as I added -fobject-code I could get ghci to produce a result in 8 minutes, which is close to the 6 minutes I get when running on the command line. I still cannot get Jupyter to play ball - I think I will just forget about that and use ghci instead.

Answer (score 0):

So mgsloan was totally correct.

The problem was all about the shell being interpreted (it ran in about 1h15m) and as soon as I added the -fobject-code on the `stack ghci --ghci-options -fobject-code` call I got the computation down to 8 minutes which is close to the 6 minutes I get when running as a compiled program.

Jupyter refuses to be fast, so I will only use that for other experiments - no clue on how to debug that or figure out how why it when from being almost as fast as the compiled program to being really slow.

Extra info: I have now added a way to write the computed results to disk using Data.Binary -look in the League.hs file if you are interested.

This approach allows me to read the results into a variable in ghci using

```
res <- TrueValue.League.loadResults "pl-201617.results"
```

The results are around 500MB, so the first time I use the value it takes about 22s to compute anything. After that it takes less than a second, often way less.

I'd like to apologise for not being clearer when I stated my question, but it was really all about why I was seeing a huge difference in execution time between the compiled program and running in ghci. mgsloan was so kind to see through that.